# PHP: Make Object Behave like array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am writing a [class](https://github.com/mjacobus/php-objects/blob/feature/hash_as_array/lib/Hash.php) (Hash) that adds behaviour to array. The instantiated objects should be interchangeable with the primitive array, so I can pass it to methods that require arrays. 
Also I want to be able to cast the object to array

The test it should pass is [here](https://github.com/mjacobus/php-objects/blob/feature/hash_as_array/tests/HashAccessTest.php#L53).

I thought implementing ArrayAccess would be enough, but it is not.

Or perhaps implementing a `__toArray()` method, like `toString()` for casting strings, but it also won't work.

**edit:**

```
$hash = new Hash(array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'bar' => 'barfoo',
));

function echoArray(array $array) {
    print_r($array);
}

echoArray($hash); 
// Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to echoArray() 
// must be of the type array, object given

print_r((array) $hash);
/*
Array
(
    [*_values] => Array
        (
            [foo] => bar
            [bar] => barfoo
        )
)
*/
```

Is there a way of achieving that behaviour?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea...was there a question here?

Comment: This isn't really about the original post but noticed that you are using get_called_class() in Hash.php:164. If you want to avoid it, you can try dropping it off and use "new static($params);" on Hash.php:165.

Comment: @NikoHujanen Depends on which version of PHP he must support (regarding get_called_class()-post above).

Comment: The problem is with your unit test. assertEquals will always fail if you simply cast an object like that. Afaik you can't override type casting in PHP(?)

Comment: @NikoHujanen, I'll check that. Thanks. But I don't think that is supported in v. 5.3.3.

Comment: @blockhead. I edited the question to make my point more clear. Tks!

Comment: @frodeborli. There may be a problem in the test also, but there is also a problem in the Hash implementation. I edited the question with two examples that fail. Tks.

Comment: @Marcelo, I think the support came with 5.3.0's late static binding (http://fi2.php.net/lsb). get_called_class() also relays on 5.3.0's LSB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sadly not possible for a lot of internal functions that require primitive arrays to use your object as such. Yes, user defined PHP function can use it as an array (although not if you require an argument to be a primitive array), but stuff like `array_map`... won't:

```
<?php
class obj implements arrayaccess {
    private $container = array();
    public function __construct() {
        $this->container = array(
            "one"   => 1,
            "two"   => 2,
            "three" => 3,
        );
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
}

$obj = new obj;

function requirearray(array $obj){};

requirearray($obj);
// Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to requirearray() must be of the type array, object given...

var_dump(array_map('strlen',$obj));
// Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array
// NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting your description:

> implementing ArrayAccess would be enough

Here's the documentation: **[PHP ArrayAcces interface](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)**

I don't think there's anything more to say. I can eventually add an example:

```
class SomeClassImplementingArrayAccess implements arrayaccess {
    // implements all required methods
}

$arrayAccessObj = new SomeClassImplementingArrayAccess();
$arrayAccessObj['abc'] = 'def'; //it calls the `SomeClassImplementingArrayAccess::offsetSet` method
$objValueABC = $arrayAccessObj['abc']; //it calls the `SomeClassImplementingArrayAccess::offsetGet` method
```

Comment: Thank you @matewka. But the fact is that implementing the ArrayAccess is not enough. Something else must be done.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has no toArray() method in the ArrayAccess interface. I think this assertion will succeed:

```
$hash = new Hash($array);
$this->assertEqual($array, $hash->toArray());
```

The phpunit test will not succeed, since casting an object to an array results in an array with the properties of said object.

However, the object should work as an array in its current form.

PS: In your offsetGet-implementation, you should check if you are returning an array. In that case, I would wrap the result in a new Hash-object. If you are careful about references (using the &-operator), changes will propagate to the parent Hash.

That is:

Currently

```
$array["somekey"][] = "Something";
```

will work, but

```
$object["somekey"][] = "Something";
```

will fail.

You can also detect changes in "sub-hashes" and keep a reference to a parent hash - and replace the parent:

In offsetSet:

```
if($this->parent) $this->parent->values[$this->keyInParent] = $this->values;
```

In offsetGet:

```
if(is_array($this->values[$key])) {
    $hash = new Hash($this->values[$key]);
    $hash->parent = $this;
    $hash->keyInParent = $key;
    return $hash;
}
```

Comment: I liked your offsetGet suggestion, although I would rather check for arrays in the offsetSet implementation. I will open an issue about that so I will not forget it. Tks!

Comment: @Marcelo Then you must also iterate the entire array in the constructor, which I think will be highly inefficient.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. =/

Comment: @Marcelo I've updated my response with the only solution that'll work. You simply can't cast to an array in your ->assertEquals().